# How can I select one row value from several columns following a loop?

Tags: r, loops, min

I have this in my "info" dataframe:

```
                   sci wd.sps1 wd.sps2 wd.genus wd.family
1    Acacia polyphylla  0.6185  0.6185   0.6335      0.69
2    Acacia polyphylla  0.6185  0.6185   0.6335      0.69
3    Acacia polyphylla  0.6185  0.6185   0.6335      0.69
4    Acacia polyphylla  0.6185  0.6185   0.6335      0.69
5      Acosmium nitens  0.8200  0.8200   0.8100      0.69
6      Acosmium nitens  0.8200  0.8200   0.8100      0.69
7           Aiouea sp.      NA      NA   0.3700      0.55
8           Aiouea sp.      NA      NA   0.3700      0.55
9  Allophylus robustus      NA      NA   0.3900      0.73
10 Allophylus robustus      NA      NA   0.3900      0.73
```

And I came up with this loop to get the first wd.____ value that appears in the dataframe ( i.e. it should get 0.6185 for the row 1, 0.3700 for line 7, and 0.3900 for line 10):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(info)) {
    if( all( is.na (info[i,c("wd.sps1","wd.sps2", "wd.genus", "wd.family")]))) {
        next()   
    }   
    info[i,]$wd = with(info[i,], c(wd.sps1, wd.sps2, wd.genus, 
      wd.family)[min( which( !is.na( c(wd.sps1, wd.sps2, wd.genus, wd.family))))]
    ) 
}
```

I have used a similar loop with a different dataframe and it worked but this time I keep getting an error that I don't understand...

Comment: Don't keep us in suspense.  What was the error?

Comment: Sorry! It was not actually an error but a warning message... Still, it was not getting the values into a new colummn

Answer (score 0):

An approach utilizing `apply()`

```
info$wd <- apply(info[,c("wd.sps1","wd.sps2", "wd.genus","wd.family")],
                 1,function(x)na.omit(x)[1])
```

I'm sure it can be done more efficiently, but this was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: This is a really more intelligent way to do it! It makes my R coding looks really lame lol... Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

Also,

```
indx <- which(!is.na(info[,-1]),arr.ind=T)
info$wd <- info[,-1][indx[!duplicated(indx[,1]),]]
info$wd
#[1] 0.6185 0.6185 0.6185 0.6185 0.8200 0.8200 0.3700 0.3700 0.3900 0.3900
```